# Number of Conjugates is Number of Cosets of Centralizer (proof of)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The following proof is from Czesław Bagiński, "Introduction to group theory". The original is in Polish, the translation below is mine.

> **Definition**. Let $G$ be a group and $x, y \in G$. Then
> $$x^y := y^{-1}xy.$$
> **Definition.** $C_x:=\{y \in G: \exists_{z \in G}\ y = x^z\}$.
> **Definition 10.1.** By the *centralizer of an element $g$* in a group $G$ we call the set of all elements of that group which are commutative with $g$:
> $$C_G(g) = \{x \in G: gx = xg \}.$$
> By the centralizer of a subset $A$ of a group $G$ we call the set of all these elements of $G$ which are commutative with all elements of $A$. In other words the centralizer of the set $A$ is the intersection of the centralizers of all elements belonging to $A$:
> $$C_G(A) = \{x \in G: \forall_{a \in A}\ ax = xa\}.$$

> **Definition 10.2.** We call elements $x$ and $y$ of a group $G$ conjugates if and only if there exists an element $z \in G$ such that
> $$y = z^{-1}xz = x^z.$$

> **Theorem 10.3.** Let $x$ be an element of a group $G$. Then the number of conjugates of $x$ is equal to the index of the centralizer of $x$:
> $$|C_x| = |G : C_G(x)|.$$
> In particular, if $G$ is a finite group then the number of any class of of conjugates divides the order of the group $G$.
>
> **Proof.** In the proof we will accept that $C = C_G (x)$ . Let us represent the group $G$ as a union of the cosets of $G$ with respect to $C$ : $G= Cg_1 \cup Cg_2 \cup Cg_3 \cup \ldots$ . Let $y = x^g$ be any conjugate of the element $x$. Since $g$ lies in some uniquely defined coset $C g_m$ thus $g = hg_m$ for some $h \in C$ and this implies that $y=x^g = x^{hg_m} = (x^h)^{g_m} = x^{g_m}$. Thus the number of the set of conjugates of $x$ does not exceed the number of cosets. Next, if $Cg_m \neq Cg_k$ then $Cg_m g_k^{-1} \neq C$ which means that $x^{g_m} \neq x^{g_k}$ which in turn means that $x^{g_m g_{k}^{-1}} \neq x$. Thus the number of cosets of the group $G$ with respect to $C$ does not exceed the number of conjugates of $x$. By that the theorem is proven.

How can one show that indeed $ x^ {g_m g_k^{-1}} \neq x$? I didn't succeed in showing it, but I tried to do that by:
(1) exploiting the fact that $x ^ {g_m g_k^{-1}} \neq x$ means that $g_m g_k^{-1}$ does not lie in the coset being the neutral element. But then all what I see I have is that $(g_m g_k^{-1})^{-1} x \neq x$ but it does not imply anything about $(g_m g_k^{-1})^{-1} x (g_m g_k^{-1})$,
(2) trying to prove that $(g_m g_k^{-1})^{-1}$ should be an element of $C$ but I've found no reason for that to be the case,
(3) trying to conclude that $Cg_m g_k^{-1} \neq x$ somehow more directly by the definition of $x^y$ but also no success.

Comment: Why are you asking about $Cg_mg_k^{-1}\ne x$, when that isn't anywhere in the proof you quote? What's in the proof is $Cg_mg_k^{-1}\ne C$.

Comment: In any case $Cg_mg_k^{-1} \ne x$ doesn't make sense because the LHS is a coset and the RHS is an element.

Comment: Sorry, there were mistakes. I corrected the post.

Comment: You have a $C_x$ which is undefined. You have a string of $C_{g_i}$ which I suspect are $Cg_i$. [In other words I  think by $C_x$ you mean a conjugacy class but the $C_{g_i}$ are cosets.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician: Yes, thank you for pointing that out (others too for pointing out other errors), I edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $x^ {g_m g_k^{-1}} = x$ if and only if $g_m g_{k}^{-1}$ centralises $x$, that is if and only if $g_m g_{k}^{-1}\in C$; this happens if and only if $Cg_m g_{k}^{-1}=C$, that is if and only if $Cg_m =C g_k$ which is false by assumption.

(2) $t$ commutes with $x$ if and only if $t^{-1}$ commutes with $x$.

Comment: This answers what I was really after, thanks. However, regarding the point (2) - I'm aware of that property but do we have that $g_m g_k^{-1}$ itself is an element of $C$?

Comment: Yes, the argument in (1) surely gives that?

Comment: Yes, you showed it explicitly. It seems I was overthinking it.